# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, nswindowcontroller

OK, the situation is a bit complicated but the nature of the issue itself should be pretty simple for anyone more familiar than me with me Cocoa memory management.

A few details :
- From my main app, I'm loading a "loadable" bundle (which consists of an `NSWindowController`)
- Both projects (the main app and the "plugin") are ARC-enabled

In my plugin code, I have a custom initialization method :

```
- (id)initWithAPI:(id)api
{
    pluginWindowController* newPluginWindowController = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"PluginWindow"];

    if (newPluginWindowController)
    {
        [newPluginWindowController setAPI:api];
    }

    return newPluginWindowController;

}
```

This is how `API` is declared :

```
@property (unsafe_unretained) id API;
```

Now, here's the catch :

- I'm initializing using `initWithAPI:` and `API` is being set.
- When I'm testing `API`'s value in `- (void)windowDidLoad:` it still shows up fine.
- However : when trying to do the very same thing from within another method (actually an IBAction triggered by a button click in my plugin's window)... trying to get `[self API]` triggers an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either declare the property as `weak`, if you want it to automatically be set to `nil` when the object dies, or as `strong`, if you want to keep the object alive (`strong` is probably what you want).

`unsafe_unretained` will result in a dangling pointer if the object is deallocated (that's why its called "unsafe"..)